# Contraction: Precompactness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Given Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$.

For precompactness:
$$\tau\in\mathcal{C}(X,Y):\quad\overline{A}\text{ compact}\implies\overline{\tau(A)}\text{ compact}$$

Is this true and why?

Comment: The continuous image of a compact set is ... (think open cover)

Comment: @TrialAndError: Yes but the problem is that: It is only precompact and the image of its closure under the extension may fail to be bijective onto the closure of the original range.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal L(X,Y)$ instead of $\mathcal L(A,B)$?

Comment: Bounded $\tau$ extends boundedly to $\overline{A}$. Image of $\overline{A}$ under $\overline{\tau}$ is compact. $B \subseteq \tau(A)\subseteq\overline{\tau}(\overline{A})=compact$. Closed subset of compact = compact. $\overline{B}$ is compact.

Comment: Now you're talking about linear maps from $A$ to $B$ where neither $A$ nor $B$ is a vector space. Makes no sense. Do us a favor - _think_ about what you really mean to ask...

Comment: @TrialAndError: But one only has: $\overline{\tau}(\overline{A})\subseteq\overline{\overline{\tau}(A)}= \overline{B}$

Comment: @Freeze_S But $\tau(A) \subset \overline{\tau}(\overline{A})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Great thanks to TrialAndError and Daniel Fischer!!*

For Hausdorff spaces:
$$\overline{\tau(A)}\subseteq\overline{\tau({\overline{A}})}=\overline{\tau}(\overline{A})$$

Concluding compactness.